# Is there any alternative to Youtube Data API Activities.list endpoint's home parameter?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to build a YouTube clone in Android using the YouTube Data API. I want to show a section in which the user sees video items that are similar to those seen on the user's YouTube home page. It used to be a parameter called [`home`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list#home) in the [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list)  API endpoint, but YouTube have deprecated it. Can anyone give me a workaround this?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: I gave up and became a C# developer